# Navigation Issue while navigating using Android Hardware Back Press [react-native]

Tags: javascript, react-native

When I navigate to the first screen from the final screen of my App using hardware back press
**It initially navigates to first screen and also bounces back to the final screen**

Also the animation that I have given in the first screen becomes **a stuck and play like experience** while navigating and this case is same for both types of navigation ie.,

-navigating with the back button in App and also while using hardware back press

This is my final screen js file where I handle hardware back press:

```js
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.handleBack = (() => {
    Actions.FirstScreen();
  });
 }

  componentDidMount() {
    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBack);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
   BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBack);
 }
```

and this is the first screen's js file where I have the animation:

```js
  componentWillMount() {
    this.slide1 = new Animated.Value(0);
    this.slide2 = new Animated.Value(0);
    this.bnt1();
    this.bnt2();
 }

 bnt1() {
       Animated.timing(
         this.slide1, {
           delay: 100,
           toValue: w / 1.33,
           duration: 700,
       }
       ).start();
     }

     bnt2() {
           Animated.timing(
             this.slide2, {
               delay: 700,
               toValue: -(w / 1.33),
               duration: 500,
           }
           ).start();
         }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `final screen js file` add this:

```js
constructor(props) {
     super(props);
      this.handleBack = (() => {
        Actions.FirstScreen();
        return true;
       });
      }
```